# How to access our election voting history?

Tags: support, moderator-election

[Election](https://stackoverflow.com/election) season has come up in Stack Overflow, and I have already voted in the previous two elections. I want to know whether we can see our election voting history: who I voted for during the previous two elections. I'd also like to see the election results.

Answer (score 19):

[It remains visible on the side bar of the last election you participated in.](https://stackoverflow.com/election/9?tab=election)

Comment: Not only the last election, all previous ones (at least for me, it could be that very old elections are missing). And make sure you select the 'election' tab (which your link does because of the `?tab=reputation`); the default tab is 'nomination' and then it won't be shown.

Comment: I'd like to add that https://stackoverflow.com/election/0 works to see an overview of all election results. It feels like a hack, because 0 is an invalid number and it apparently decides to show an overview of all elections in that case. Not sure what the proper URL would be.

Comment: @Justastudent see my question [How to show the election history page when there is an ongoing election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301637/295232)

Comment: It is scary how that Q&A pair is *exactly* the process I went through, up to and including Shadow Wizard's comment. Thank you @Glorfindel. I still think it would make sense to include that information in this answer, possibly even linking to the Meta SE Q&A.

Answer (score 3):

The first part of your question has been [answered by @Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364730/4751173).

> I'd also like to see the election results.

As [@Justastudent notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364729/how-to-access-our-election-voting-history/364730?noredirect=1#comment566157_364730), this is possible by visiting this link: https://stackoverflow.com/election/0

More details can be found on Meta Stack Exchange: [How to show the election history page when there is an ongoing election?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301637/295232).